# How to sort strings on two conditions without an array/algorithms in c++?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, c++11, stdstring

I am trying to do a program where a user inputs three names and they get sorted.
 The conditions are that each name gets inputted like "firstname lastname" and then I need to sort the names on lastname, but if the lastname is the same for two entries I need to sort on the firstname.

I have solved how to sort on just the firstname OR lastname, but am getting stuck on how to sort on both. Any ideas how I can implement more conditional sorting without using an array or `<algorithm>` in c++?

For each input I do this to split the input to firstname and lastname to lowercase:

```
cout << "Input name1: " << endl;
getline(cin, input1);
input1_old = input1;

size_t found = input1.find(space);
for (int i = 0; i < input1.size(); i++)
{
    input1[i] = tolower(input1[i]);
}
input1Last = input1.substr(found + 1, string::npos);
input1First = input1.substr(0, found);
```

Then I "sort" like this:

```
if (input1Last <= input2Last && input2Last <= input3Last)
{
    cout << input1_old << '\n' << input2_old << '\n' << input3_old << endl;
}
else if (input1Last <= input3Last && input3Last <= input2Last)
{
    cout << input1_old << '\n' << input3_old << '\n' << input2_old << endl;
}
else if (input2Last <= input1Last && input1Last <= input3Last)
{
    cout << input2_old << '\n' << input1_old << '\n' << input3_old << endl;
}
else if (input2Last <= input3Last && input3Last <= input1Last)
{
    cout << input2_old << '\n' << input3_old << '\n' << input1Last << endl;
}
else if (input3Last <= input1Last && input1Last <= input2Last)
{
    cout << input3_old << '\n' << input1_old << '\n' << input2_old << endl;
}
if (input3Last <= input2Last && input2Last <= input1Last)
{
    cout << input3_old << '\n' << input2_old << '\n' << input1Last << endl;
}
```

Comment: maybe he means <algorithm>?

Comment: Why are you restricting yourself to not use an array? This severely limits how much  your solution will scale to larger sets of input.

Comment: Yes I mean <algorithm>, I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I'd recommend breaking the comparison into a different function like you would if you were going to use `std::sort`. Then you can focus on getting the sorting logic working and the comparison logic working independently.

Comment: Lol.. why would anyone limit themselves like this.. Writes every possible combination of sorting with if-statements rather than writing a sort algorithm..

Comment: probably some type of homework :D

Comment: I would dodge that silly 'no array' requirement somehow. No arrays? How about `initializer_list`s then? No init lists? Then tuples! No `std` tuples? Make your own.

Comment: It sounds like your teacher wants you to learn (and practice) how to nest `if` statements.

Comment: Are you allowed to copy variables?  Instead of going straight to `cout` have your `if` statements use copying to fix the last name order.  Then use copying again to fix the first name order.

Comment: Add them to a binary tree, then traverse it in the appropriate order to get your output?

Comment: @Bob__ *It sounds like your teacher wants you to learn (and practice) how to nest if statements.* -- And how to handle rejection when a company code review process looks at the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To swap first and last names, use the following trick:

- Reverse the entire string
- Reverse the individual names in the string

To do this, you should write a function that reverses a string between two indices, and you will need to use `string::find()` (or a loop) to find the space between the names.

To sort three items, use the following trick:

- sort the first two items
- sort the last two items
- sort the first two items

Again, sorting two items is perfect for a function.

Hints:

```
void reverse( string& s, int first, int last );
void sort( string& a, string& b );  // swap a and b if !(a < b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I managed to solve it by reversing the entire string and then just doing the "sorting" as before! :- )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a homework question and you shouldn't use macros or try to cleverly avoid restrictions:

Use string concatenation (strcat in standard C library) to join two string together. Use " " to separate them. This will preserve the lexicographical order and reduce the problem to the one already solved :)

Use the 6 if clauses you've already made for selecting proper order of the resulting (single) string.

In c++ you can just use operator+ to join strings.

If you cannot print the resulting single string (the order of printing and comparison are different) - you have to split them (strtok) and reverse the first/last name before printing.

@EDIT
Also, while we're at it, you can just use `std::cin >> firstName >> lastName` to read strings (it will read until first whitespace) and lowercase them char by char in the same loop using [std::string::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/) to access chars

Comment: Don't use `strcat` when you have `std::string` objects. Just use `operator+`.